# How do you make code refresh itself at regular intervals in JavaFX?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, clock

I am trying to create a clock program and I am new to javaFX programming, my code reads as follows:

```
package clock;

import java.util.Calendar;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;
 /**
 *
 * @author Jaskey     */
public class Clock extends Application {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

private ImageView secondHand;
private ImageView minuteHand;
private ImageView hourHand;
private Calendar realTime = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = realTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = realTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = realTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Clock 0.03");
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    Circle clock = new Circle(150,Color.DARKGRAY);
    clock.setEffect(new Glow(0.6f));
    clock.setEffect(new InnerShadow(15, Color.BEIGE));
    clock.setEffect(new DropShadow());



    Circle clockCentre = new Circle(7,Color.THISTLE);
    clockCentre.setEffect(new Shadow());
    clockCentre.setEffect(new BoxBlur());



     minuteHand = new ImageView(new Image(Clock.class.getResourceAsStream("images/minuteHand.png")));
     minuteHand.setFitHeight(370);
     minuteHand.setFitWidth(370);
     minuteHand.setOpacity(0.85f);


    secondHand = new ImageView(new Image(Clock.class.getResourceAsStream("images/secondHand.png")));
    secondHand.setFitHeight(370);
    secondHand.setFitWidth(370);
    secondHand.setOpacity(0.85f);


    hourHand = new ImageView(new Image(Clock.class.getResourceAsStream("images/hourHand.png")));
    hourHand.setFitHeight(370);
    hourHand.setFitWidth(370);
    hourHand.setOpacity(0.85f);



    if(seconds == seconds){

        secondHand.setRotate(seconds*6);

    }

            if(minutes == minutes){

        minuteHand.setRotate(minutes*6);

    }

         if(hours == hours){

        hourHand.setRotate(hours*30);

    }






       final Timeline timelineSeconds = new Timeline();
    timelineSeconds.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timelineSeconds.setAutoReverse(false);
    final KeyValue SecondHand = new KeyValue(secondHand.rotateProperty(), 360);
    final KeyFrame seconds2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(60), SecondHand);
    timelineSeconds.getKeyFrames().addAll(seconds2);
    timelineSeconds.play();

       final Timeline timelineMinutes = new Timeline();
    timelineMinutes.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timelineMinutes.setAutoReverse(false);
    final KeyValue MinuteHand = new KeyValue(minuteHand.rotateProperty(), 360);
    final KeyFrame minutes2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.minutes(60), MinuteHand);
    timelineMinutes.getKeyFrames().add(minutes2);
    timelineMinutes.play();

           final Timeline timelineHours = new Timeline();
    timelineHours.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timelineHours.setAutoReverse(false);
    final KeyValue HourHand = new KeyValue(hourHand.rotateProperty(), 360);
    final KeyFrame hours2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.hours(12), HourHand);
    timelineHours.getKeyFrames().add(hours2);
    timelineHours.play();





    StackPane root = new StackPane();


    root.getChildren().addAll(clock, clockCentre, hourHand, minuteHand, secondHand);
    Scene myScene = new Scene(root, 650, 450);
    myScene.setFill(null);
    primaryStage.setScene((myScene));
    primaryStage.show();


        }
}
```

The clock hands were working fine (just not in time with the current time), so I added this part of the code to fix the problem:

```
if(seconds == seconds){

        secondHand.setRotate(seconds*6);

    }

            if(minutes == minutes){

        minuteHand.setRotate(minutes*6);

    }

         if(hours == hours){

        hourHand.setRotate(hours*30);

    }
```

The only problem is every minute this causes the second hand to jolt, and every hour the minute hand and every half day for the hour hand. I know the solution to the problem lies with refreshing the code above every 59 seconds - that is where I need help - How do I make it refresh itself every 59 seconds???!

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can find basically 3 classes that manipulate chronological time in JavaFX. Among them we have, [KeyValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html), [keyframe](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html), and [TimeLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html). They all work together and become an extension of the basic API of JavaFX animation (the other part is reserved for the transitions). Beyond that, you will find a very similar class with the Swing Timer class, known as [AnimationTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).

You can learn how to use all these classes properly right [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CIHHAACG).

What I suggest that you do is read this article. While you are reading, look at the documentation for each class that is mentioned in it. Sooner or later you will understand perfectly how to use them.

At first moment, I got the idea that you can start an animation of 60 seconds, updating the seconds of your clock. This animation will be running indefinitely. Once the animation is finished, use the event generated by the end of the animation to update the other parts of your clock. With this update you can trigger other animations that simply update the minutes and hours.

Let it be clear that this is not a final idea. I'm just suggesting you something that you will see in time the best way to be able to build your watch. When you finish reading the links I gave you, check out my idea again and start to come up with a strategy that manages updates, and animations only WHEN needed. In your code, all you're doing is connecting node properties to the animations objects, and hitting the "play button". Do not do this. Make your clock behave in synchronism **when** the seconds pass or something happens (got it?).

If you still have questions, comment here and I will help you. :)

Good luck.